# Convert this jQuery snippet to vanilla javascript (focus not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to convert this jQuery snippet into vanilla JavaScript and I seem to be having an issue with the **focus** and **blur** events.

I can't seem to get my callback function to execute on those events.

**Why does the jQuery snippet work and not mine?**

**HTML Snippet**

```
form(class="form js-form" method="post" action="/contact")
  div.row
    div.col-sm-12
      div.form__group.js-form-group
        label(class="form__label js-form-label" for="name") Name
        input(class="form__input js-form-input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required)

  div.row
    div.col-sm-12
      div.form__group.js-form-group
        label(class="form__label js-form-label" for="email") Email
        input(class="form__input js-form-input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required)
  div.row
    div.col-sm-6
      div.form__group.js-form-group
        label(class="form__label js-form-label" for="occasion") Occasion
        input(class="form__input js-form-input" type="text" name="occasion" id="occasion" placeholder="Occasion" required)
    div.col-sm-6
      div.form__group.js-form-group
        label(class="form__label js-form-label" for="date") Date
        input(class="form__input js-form-input" type="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" required)
  div.row
   div.col-sm-12
     div.form__group.js-form-group
       label(class="form__label js-form-label" for="message")
       textarea(class="form__textarea js-form-input" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required)
  div.row
    div.col-sm-12
      button.pull-right(class="form__submit js-form-submit" type="submit") Submit
```

**jQuery Snippet**

```
$(function() {
  $(".js-form").on("input propertychange", ".js-form-group", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("has-value", !!$(e.target).val());
    console.log(this);
  }).on("focus", ".js-form-group", function() {
    $(this).addClass("focused");
    console.log('focus');
  }).on("blur", ".js-form-group", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("focused");
    console.log("blur");
  });

});
```

**Vanilla Snippet That Isn't Working**

```
var formFloatingLabels = (function() {
  var formSelector = 'js-form',
    formGroupSelector = 'js-form-group',
    form = document.getElementsByClassName(formSelector)[0], 
    formGroup = null,
    focusedClass = 'focused',
    hasValueClass = 'has-value';

  if (!form) {
    return;
  }

  formGroup = form.getElementsByClassName(formGroupSelector);



  function init() {
    bindFormGroupEventListeners();
  }

  function toggleHasValueClass() {
    this.classList.toggle(hasValueClass);
  }

  function addFocusedClass() {
    console.log('focused');
  }

  function removeFocusedClass() {
    console.log('blurred');
  }

  function bindFormGroupEventListeners() {
    var currentFormGroup = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < formGroup.length; i++) {
      currentFormGroup = formGroup[i];

      currentFormGroup.addEventListener('input', toggleHasValueClass);
      currentFormGroup.addEventListener('focus', addFocusedClass);
      currentFormGroup.addEventListener('blur', removeFocusedClass);


    }
  }

  return {
    init: init
  }
})();

formFloatingLabels.init();
```

Comment: I think focus is not achieved by adding a class. It is a method of an element `focus()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: @MirkoVukušić - the class 'focused' is my own css class that I made. However that never gets added because the **addEventListener('focus'...)** is never triggered. My question is why?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the jQuery code works.

'focus' and 'blur' are native `<input>` events.

To make your code work, either change `formGroupSelector = 'js-form-group',` to `formGroupSelector = 'js-form-input',` or change the input tag to have a class of `js-form-group`.

Here's a small working duplicate of your code in jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/wiwori/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Btw, nice job for ditching jQuery, great way to learn about javascript.

**UPDATE**

I do know why jQuery works. http://api.jquery.com/on/

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest, innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create consistent cross-browser behavior.

And

> The focus and blur events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser focusin and focusout events that do bubble. When focus and blur are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as focusin and focusout respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names.

Simply put, because you used 'on' jQuery bubbled the focus event up to the div, this is not the native browser behaviour.

Comment: Its very odd - im not sure what else jQuery is doing in order to achieve this

Comment: Really not sure, even the jquery guide states: "This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links (<a href>)"

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Ah I see - so because this is delegated and jquery has its own pollyfill?

Answer (score 0):

Using

`$(function () { //... })`

has the same effect as using:

`$(document).ready(function () { //... })`

The jQuery snippet waits for a `DOMContentLoaded` event. Yours does not. That might just be the cause of the issue. Try replacing the last line with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', formFloatingLabels.init, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `focus` and `blur` to work on non-input type elements, they have to have a tabindex.

If you give a tabindex to an element you will receive a focus event when it is clicked.